# No code assist inside lambda function in eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8, code-assist

i am using eclipse neon 4.6.0

when i try to use lambda functions, the eclipse code assist does not work inside the lamdba functions. But it works fine outside the lambda function.

additional note: my java compiler preferences are set to 1.8 in eclipse preferences.

Comment: As I cannot see anything the SO community can do for you, I suggest you file a bug at bugs.eclipse.org. It is well known, that eclipse support of java 8 features still is a bit "problematic" here and there.

Comment: Unfortunately there are currently several known bugs about completion in lambdas failing in Eclipse IDE. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?classification=Eclipse&list_id=15080816&product=JDT&query_format=advanced&resolution=---&short_desc=lambda%20assist&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr . Those are currently seriously worked on, but any help would be welcome and would definitely speed up the delivery of a good completion in lambda. Feel free to participate to the bugs you're the most interested in, some would welcome an example.

Comment: It would help if you raise a bug for your specific case at Eclipse. It is possible there is already a bug open, if so do mention on the bug that you are affected too. Anyway, I few bugs were resolved in this area in the recent past, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501440, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495912 etc..